# Android. ConstraintLayout, how to apply goneMargin

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, margin, android-constraintlayout

I have layout with ConstraintLayout as parent. Inside my constraint layout there are three views: ImageView and two TextView. I need, depending on whether the visibility of the ImageView and the TextView (1) is visible or not, the margin  top of the second TextView changes. This is a visual example of what I want to implement:
[image]

I tried using goneMarginTop = 32 for my second TextView. However, in this case, as soon as the visibility of the first TextView is gone, I get margin between ImageView and TextView = 32 dp but  expected 12 dp. I need margin = 32 dp only when ImageView and first TextView are gone. Here is my code:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"  
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView         
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"       
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivImage"
            app:layout_goneMarginTop="32dp" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_goneMarginTop="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"         
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"        
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"          />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is it possible to implement the behavior as in the image using ConstraintLayout from layout (not programmatically).

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do what you ask just with XML and `gone` margins. You can do it programmatically like it is suggested, but you can also get the spacing you want by using a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier) and a [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) widget. See the comments in the sample XML below. (I added background colors and a visible horizontal marker at `32dp` to show the extent of the widgets)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--
        Space is set to the top of the layout with a height of 20dp.
    -->
    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--
        A barrier is set to the bottom of the Space above and the bottom TextView (tvDesc). The
        vertical placement of this barrier will vary from the bottom of tvTitle when 
        tvTitle is visible to 20dp (the bottom of the Space widget) when tvTitle is gone.
    -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="space,tvTitle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivImage"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="20dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!--
        The top constraint of tvDesc is set to the barrier and the top margin is set to 12dp. If
        tvTitle and the ImageView are gone, the top margin will still be 12dp. Since the 
        minimum vertical placement of the barrier is 20dp (the height of the Space widget) the 
        effective top margin for tvDesc will be 32dp (20dp + 12dp) as desired.
    -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**All views visible:**

[image]

**tvTitle `gone`**

[image]

**ImageView and tvTitle `gone`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it programmatically :

```
  val layoutParams = imageView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
  layoutParams.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)
```